# show employees' salary history by adding StartingSalary and Increase values Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

On a form, I have a chart that shows the Increase History of each employee (What rating they were given each year, and how much of an increase they got)

I can't post an image since I have less than 10 reputation, but I hope it's clear.

What I need is a similar graph, but for the history of each employee's salary. I have a StartingSalary field in IncreaseEmployeesQ, and an Increase field. It's complicated, all I've managed to do is this:

```
SELECT IncreaseEmployeesQ.LocalID, Sum([Increase]+[StartingSalary]) AS CurrentSalary

FROM IncreaseEmployeesQ

GROUP BY IncreaseEmployeesQ.LocalID;
```

But what this does is add the StartingSalary each time, since it's repeated in each year. and it gives me one value for each employee, instead of one value for each year so I can have a chart that tracks the progress of the employee's salary.

I tried going to the original IncreaesT instead of the query that has it and EmployeesT (IncreaseEmployeesQ), thinking maybe I can have a calculated field if I add a StartingSalary field in IncreaseT (It's originally in EmployeesT) and then link it in relationships and enforce referential integrity, but I kept getting an error message. After some research I gathered that the reason is because the two tables have different Primary keys, so I resorted to the Query.

Is the chart I'm aiming to get to even possible? a chart that shows how each employee's salary has been progressing since 2010? (that's as far back as my data goes)

---

-assuming that a query is the right way to get this done- The query I'm working on looks like this:

```
LocalID    Increase    Years   StartingSalary
1          1000        2013    7000
1          500         2014    7000
1          0           2015    7000
1          500         2016    7000
2          0           2013    5000
2          500         2014    5000
2          500         2015    5000
2          0           2016    5000
```

What I want it to look like (so I make a chart later) is this:

```
LocalID    Increase    Years   StartingSalary   CurrentSalary
1          1000        2013    7000              8000
1          500         2014    7000              8500
1          0           2015    7000              8500
1          500         2016    7000              9000
2          0           2013    5000              5000
2          500         2014    5000              5500
2          500         2015    5000              6000
2          0           2016    5000              6000
```

If it turns out like this, I can make a chart that has the Years and the CurrentSalary for each employee.

But all I've managed to do is the code above, which gives me this result

```
LocalID    Increase    Years   StartingSalary    CurrentSalary
1          1000        2013    7000              30000
1          500         2014    7000              30000
1          0           2015    7000              30000
1          500         2016    7000              30000
2          0           2013    5000              21000
2          500         2014    5000              21000
2          500         2015    5000              21000
2          0           2016    5000              21000
```

I hope everything is clear now

Comment: `I can't post an image` No, but you can provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements, AND a desired result - which is infinitely better

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, can you clearify?

Comment: I thought maybe my question wasn't clear, I added some stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum.  One way to do this in MS Access uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ieq.*,
       (ieq.StartingSalary +
        (SELECT SUM(increase)
         FROM IncreaseEmployeesQ as ieq2
         WHERE ieq2.LocalID = ieq.LocalId AND ieq2.Years <= ieq.Years
        )
       ) as CurrentSalary
FROM IncreaseEmployeesQ as ieq
```